# Efficient creating of SQLite db with Qt desktop app

Tags: sqlite, qt, resources

I have a small desktop application that stores its data in an SQLite db.

Currently, when the app is first run (or the user wants to create a new config) I just delete the db file and run a load of *QSqlQuery.exec("CREATE TABLE...")* statements.

When I realised I had to change the db structure, this lead to a fair bit of work hunting down all the SQL I had used and updating it to work. So now I am trying to come up with a more modular approach to storing the SQL\creating tables...

My first idea was to store the SQL statements for creating the db in a text file, as a Qt resource, but now I've actually implemented it, it feels 'clunky' (QFile->QTextStream->loop on readLine()) and doesn't allow me to format my SQL statements in the text file for readability.

Another way I could do it is to generate an empty db at compile-time and store that as a resource, but to me I think the extra size of the binary would outweigh the gains in simplicity for new db creation.

I could create a load of global const QStrings, but I like this idea least of all and would prefer to seperate non-C++\Qt from the source code if possible.

So, any ideas from the gurus out there??

Comment: @divanov how can I then use those from within my code?

Comment: @divanov Which is exactly what I am doing now with the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for a `;` at the end of a line, you can format SQL statements over multiple lines.

An empty DB file is not big if you [compress](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtiocompressor/qtiocompressor.html) it.